# how pass Bool value from one class to another class

Tags: objective-c, class, boolean

I have 2 class in objective -C in `Class A`: 
 I defined:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL fortextview;
```

and used it like:

```
   if (![_support_long_messages boolValue]) {
        [self showAlert];
        _fortextview = false;
    } else {
        _fortextview = true ;
    }
```

so the `class B` take the value of `class A` and use it like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MessagingKeyServerResponse *messaginKeyRespo;
```

MessagingKeyServerResponse Is the `class A`.

In my `class B` I defined  if statement

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
     NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
     if (_messaginKeyRespo.fortextview){
        return (newLength > MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH) ? NO : YES;
     } else {
       return (newLength > 160) ? NO : YES;
     }
}
```

The problem Is the value not pass, any help appreciate-

Comment: is Messaginkeyrespo nil in the shouldChangeTextInRange ?

Comment: YES, it shows nil.

Comment: you need to give the class A reference to the Messaginkeyrespo, otherwise it will be nil. How are you moving from class A to class B ?

Comment: then do like in your `class B` ,` @property (assign, nonatomic) MessagingKeyServerResponse *Messaginkeyrespo` and while initialising the `class B` in `class A` do like, ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] init] then next line, classB. Messaginkeyrespo = self

Comment: I didn't add reference in class A

Comment: when I add         classB.Messaginkeyrespo = self;
it give property Messaginkeyrespo not found.

Comment: when u are initialising the `class B` .. ?

Comment: I am trying to add in ClassB.h @property (readwrite, nonatomic) MessagingKeyServerResponse *Messaginkeyrespo; but the error I get is unknown type name

Answer (score 0):

Create Global variable then it works.

it solved my issue.
BOOL character_support;

Comment: Global variable works but it is not the answer for your question here